# Objective c function with variable

Tags: objective-c

Could you, please, help.
I have a lot of different savings like this

```
SaveFBProfilePicture1 = ProfilePicture1.stringValue;

DefaultProfilePicture1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultProfilePicture1 setObject:SaveFBProfilePicture1 forKey:@"SaveProfilePicture1"];
[DefaultProfilePicture1 synchronize];

SaveFBProfilePicture2 = ProfilePicture2.stringValue;
DefaultProfilePicture2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultProfilePicture2 setObject:SaveFBProfilePicture2 forKey:@"SaveProfilePicture2"];
[DefaultProfilePicture2 synchronize];

SaveFBAlbums2 = Albums2.stringValue;
DefaultAlbums2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultAlbums2 setObject:SaveFBAlbums2 forKey:@"SaveAlbums2"];
[DefaultAlbums2 synchronize];

SaveFBAbout1 = About1.stringValue;
DefaultAbout1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultAbout1 setObject:SaveFBAbout1 forKey:@"SaveAbout1"];
[DefaultAbout1 synchronize];

SaveFBAbout2 = About2.stringValue;
DefaultAbout2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[DefaultAbout2 setObject:SaveFBAbout2 forKey:@"SaveAbout2"];
[DefaultAbout2 synchronize];
```

And I don't know how it is possible to create function for this.

I need to have a function

```
- (void)SaveFB {
SaveFBxy = xy.stringValue;
Defaultxy = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[Defaultxy setObject:SaveFBxy forKey:@"Savexy"];
[Defaultxy synchronize];}
```

Where i can easiely change "x" to, for example, "About" or "Albums" and "y" to "1" or "2"

Please, help me. 
And thank you in advance!

Comment: Create function means???? What do u want exactly?

Comment: -1 don't understand what your after. Please provide more detail, also this has nothing to do with `xcode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)SaveFB:(NSString *)x:(NSString *)y
{
    NSString *value=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",x,y];
    NSString *key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Save%@%@",x,y];
    NSUserDefaults  *defaultxy = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaultxy setObject:value forKey:key];
    [defaultxy synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Answers with just code aren't very good if they don't explain themselves, so please provide an explanation in your answer not in comments

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to be pretty basic;

```
void setUserDefault(NSString* key, NSString* value) {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:value forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

...or as a class method;

```
+ (void) setUserDefault:(NSString*)key toValue:(NSString*)value {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:value forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

If setting multiple values at once, you may not want to synchronize for every single value though, it may be better to just do;

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:ProfilePicture1.stringValue forKey:@"SaveProfilePicture1"];
[userDefaults setObject:ProfilePicture2.stringValue forKey:@"SaveProfilePicture2"];
[userDefaults setObject:Albums2.stringValue forKey:@"SaveAlbums2"];
[userDefaults setObject:About1.stringValue forKey:@"SaveAbout1"];
[userDefaults setObject:About2.stringValue forKey:@"SaveAbout2"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

(synchronize is also called automatically periodically, so you may not need it at all unless you're doing this right at app exit)

Comment: Thank you very much, but is it possible to divide somehow @"SaveProfilePicture1" into "SaveProfilePicture" and "1" in order to have universal function, cuz i need to save "SaveProfilePicture1","SaveProfilePicture2","SaveAbout1".

Comment: And i'm sorry for my english. I'm not a native speaking.

Comment: @ЕвгенийМитько I'm not quite sure how you would like the calls to the function to look, could you give an example on how you would like to use it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson He's looking for a format string in the key. He just couldn't be bothered to read the `NSString` class reference.